# How to get localized names for Windows default folders in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Using Qt, I can get some default path where I can create files via e. g. `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation)` which works fine on both Linux and Windows. I also saw that one can get a localized name for the respective location via `QStandardPaths::displayName`.

The "problem" is that, on Windows, the names of some default folders are displayed localized. For the above command, I get – according to the documentation – `C:/Users/some_user/Documents`. This is probably the actual path on the disk. But what the user (with a German locale) sees is a translated version: `C:/Benutzer/some_user/Eigene Dokumente` in this case.

So, not only the last folder is translated (the string I could get via the  `QStandardPaths::displayName` call), but also the base directory.

Is there a reliable standard Qt way to be able to display the directory names the user knows from his other Windows programs?

Comment: They are not displayed localized, they are localized at system install. The actual NTFS path is the 'localized' version

Comment: I don't think you're right – when I create a file (via Qt) named `C:/Users/some_user/Documents/file`, I can access it via the Explorer by browsing `C:/Benutzer/some_user/Eigene Dokumente/`. Furthermore, if I click the path bar, a path with the English names is shown. So I don't think that the localized folders actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are looking for but I think that can give an idea. You can get a default path by accessing to the Windows Environment Variables:

In C++ is really, we have a native function for that purpose:

```
inline auto get_environement_variable(const char* key ) {
    char * val = getenv(key);
    return (val == NULL) ? "" : std::string(val);
}
```

Some of the default environment variables:

```
auto programFiles = get_environement_variable("%ProgramW6432%");
auto programFilesX86 = get_environement_variable("%ProgramFiles(x86)%");
auto userProfile = get_environement_variable("%USERPROFILE%");
```

Maybe I'm wrong but I think that this is the one for the documents folder:

```
auto userProfile = get_environement_variable("%USERPROFILE%\Documents");
```

My OS  is in English so I cannot confirm that the returned string is the translated one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this!